# How to format a 4 digit year as a date in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I pulled data into Power BI from a SQL query which returns only the order year in one of the columns.  In Power BI I formatted the column as "Data type Date" and "Date time format 2001(yyyy)", but when I pull that column into a table in Power BI, it's clearly calculating 2020 and 2021 as the number of days from 1/1/1900 (like excel) because it shows the year as 1905 for both when inserting this column into a visual, instead of years 2020 and 2021.

How can I format this column as the year 2020 and 2021?

Thank you,

Comment: you cannot format it like this, you need to change the value from 2020 to the number of days since 1/1/1900 - only then it can be formatted. You can change the column value in M/SQL, or add new calculated column assigning the year to a given date, e.g. with `DATE([YearFromSQL], 1,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it in the data source, or you can add a [custom column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-custom-column) in Power Query with M, or a [calculated column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-calculated-columns) in the model with DAX. If your data is not too much, it doesn't really matter where you will do that, but the general recommendation is to do that as close to the data source as you can (i.e. if you can, add it to your query, or if you can't add a calculated column).

The data source option needs a column in your query, which can be added with expression like this (this one uses [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) T-SQL command, if you are using another database, you will have to change it):

```
DATEFROMPARTS(ExistingYearOnlyColumn, 1, 1)
```

Or click `Transform data` to open Power Query Editor and click `Add Column` -> `Custom Column`:

[image]

and use [#date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/sharpdate) to create the date:

[image]

The last option is to create a calculated column in DAX, by right-clicking on your table and selecting `New column`:

[image]

And use [DATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/date-function-dax) DAX function in an expression like this:

```
DateColumn = DATE([ExistingYearOnlyColumn], 1, 1)
```